# Have problems installing imagemagick in particular with brew link libtiff

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew, libtiff

Basically I am trying to install imagemagick using brew and got the following error.

```
[~]$ brew install imagemagick
==> Installing imagemagick dependency: libtiff
==> Downloading http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/tiff-4.0.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libtiff-4.0.1.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.1
==> make install
Error: The linking step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link libtiff'
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.1: 239 files, 3.7M, built in 42 seconds
Error: You must `brew link libtiff' before little-cms can be installed
[~]$ brew link libtiff
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.1... 
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.1/share/man/man3/TIFFWriteDirectory.3tiff
Target /usr/local/share/man/man3/TIFFWriteDirectory.3tiff already exists. You may need to delete it.
```

Everytime I remove one, I get the error message asking me to remove another file. I have already removed like 20 of those files and I am not sure how many more are there. Is there a easier way of doing this?

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
> brew link --overwrite libtiff
```